# How to use Struts2 convention without using any action class

Tags: java, struts2, actionresult, struts2-convention-plugin

In Struts2 we can define action without using action class in `struts.xml` as follows:

```
<action name="error">
    <result>/error.jsp</result>
</action>
```

In my application I am using `struts2 convention`. In this case how to avoid writing action classes. I have many scenarios where I just want to go to the page without using any business logic.

My result path is not just a JSP. I am using tiles. I am using code as follows:

```
@Action(value="homePage", results={@Result(name="success", location="homePage", type="tiles")})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place you jsp to the `WEB-INF/content` this the default result path. Also you can change this using a constant `struts.convention.result.path`. Convention plugin creates configuration from all JSPs there. So if you have `do-something.jsp` under result path you can use `/do-something` in the browser to return this actionless result.

Comment: My result path is not just a JSP. I am using tiles. I am using code as follows: @Action(value="homePage", results={@Result(name="success", location="homePage", type="tiles")})

Comment: @user995656: You should add this information into your OP.

Comment: @user995656 Convention plugin provides configuration via scanning action classes and packages and above scenario is possible if used with convention unknown handler provided by the plugin. But convention plugin is unable to scan your tiles configuration, doesn't create actionless results from it and unable to handle them. To make it working you should write all this code yourself.

Comment: @RomanC : I got your point. I will write all this code myself.