# HTTP 404 not found error in struts2.0. but console does not show any error

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications, struts2

I am trying to create a dynamic web application in struts but the following error is shown in the web browser

> The origin server did not find a current representation for the target
>   resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Usually this error would arise due to missing libraries or pages and I would diagnose them looking at the console.
But this time the console does not show any kind of error.

Here is the console output:

```
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:32 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Game Of Thrones Quiz' did not find a matching property.
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M22
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Jun 21 2017 09:44:18 UTC
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         9.0.0.0
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_131-b11
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\user\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\user\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\user\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\endorsed
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_131/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_131/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_131/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64\compiler;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Modeltech_xe\win32xoem;C:\Program Files (x86)\Jar2Exe Wizard\;C:\Users\user\jee-neon\eclipse;;.]
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:32 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:32 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:32 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:32 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 761 ms
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M22
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:34 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:34 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts-default.xml]
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:34 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Unable to locate configuration files of the name struts-plugin.xml, skipping
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:34 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts-plugin.xml]
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:34 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts.xml]
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:34 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory)
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:34 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.ActionFactory)
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:34 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.ResultFactory)
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:34 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.ConverterFactory)
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:34 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.InterceptorFactory)
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:34 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.ValidatorFactory)
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:34 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.UnknownHandlerFactory)
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:34 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.FileManagerFactory)
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:34 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter)
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:34 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.CollectionConverter)
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:34 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.ArrayConverter)
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:34 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.DateConverter)
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:34 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.NumberConverter)
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:34 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.StringConverter)
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:34 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.ConversionPropertiesProcessor)
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:34 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.ConversionFileProcessor)
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:34 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.ConversionAnnotationProcessor)
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:34 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.TypeConverterCreator)
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:34 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.TypeConverterHolder)
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:34 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.TextProvider)
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:34 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.LocaleProvider)
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:34 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionProxyFactory)
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:34 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.ObjectTypeDeterminer)
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:34 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.mapper.ActionMapper)
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:34 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (jakarta) for (org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.multipart.MultiPartRequest)
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:34 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.views.freemarker.FreemarkerManager)
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:34 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.components.UrlRenderer)
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:34 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ActionValidatorManager)
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:34 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ValueStackFactory)
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:34 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.reflection.ReflectionProvider)
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:34 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.reflection.ReflectionContextFactory)
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:34 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.PatternMatcher)
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:34 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StaticContentLoader)
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:34 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.UnknownHandlerManager)
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:34 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.views.util.UrlHelper)
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:34 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.TextParser)
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:34 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.DispatcherErrorHandler)
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:34 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.security.ExcludedPatternsChecker)
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:34 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.security.AcceptedPatternsChecker)
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:35 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:35 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Jul 22, 2017 1:31:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2639 ms
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Game Of Thrones Quiz</display-name>

  <filter>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Home.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

struts.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC 
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <package name="Quiz1" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="submitQuiz" class="com.gameofthrones.quizResult">
            <result name="success">Stark.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

Libraries:

[image]

Error:

[image]

I tried the solutions given on similar questions but to no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ***not*** access JSP pages directly, more over they are stored under `WEB-INF` and aren't accessible by the browser.

The solution is to create a folder named `WEB-INF/content` and put files there, then use a [convention plugin](http://struts.apache.org/docs/convention-plugin.html) to create action mappings and results configuration. This folder name is used by *convention* where Struts searches resources for results.

The convention plugin *allows* access pages under `WEB-INF` directly, but you can prevent this by [Deny direct access to JSP files in Struts2 with Naming Convention plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29197214/573032).

---

Another [point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25512798/573032) is that:

> Convention plugin creates configuration from all JSPs there. So if you have `do-something.jsp` under result path you can use `/do-something` in the browser to return this *actionless* result.

Comment: But will this solve the problem? Because I have made a few such web applications before in the same way and they work without any error. Means they are accessible in the browser even if it is stored in the WEB-INF folder.

Comment: yes, it will solve it completely, I don't know what you made before, but I have helped a lot of people solving this before.

Comment: So I did as you said. Now a few new errors popped up. Like java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException  I tried removing them but couldn't.

Comment: It's worked, now you should accept and upvote this answer. Then you can post a new question. You can also post a link with a reference to this question if you need a source code.

Comment: It actually didn't work. In fact more errors arose and it is still showing me the same 404 not found error.

Comment: This is not related to your question, if you need to learn more how to ask the question and what you can ask from people who helping you [read](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)